# Convert AWK command to sqlite query

Tags: sql, awk, sqlite

I have to parse very big (abt 40Gb) text files(logs) very often.
Usually AWK/grep is enough for my needs, but logs are growing and now I'm curious whether sqlite3 will allow me to do the same things more efficiently.
I chosen sqlite for my tests as it installed out-of-the-box (SQLite version 3.6.4) on my Linux machine and more complicated tools would introduce too much overhead in this simple task.

Here is one of my usual awk queries (I simplified log structure in this example, actually it consists of more than 50 fields):

```
zcat log*.gz | awk -F'|' '{total+=$1;total+=$2;if($3==404){failed+=$1;failed+=$2}}END{print "Total="total,"\nfailed="failed,"\nRatio="failed/total}'
```

So here we summarize values of fields 1 and 2 in variable 'total' and also separately we sum them if field3==404 in variable 'failed', then calculate ratio via division.

I converted my log into sqlite DB and was ready to start performance test...but found that sqlite doesn't support stored procedures (I'm not SQL person, so it was my first time when I checked and started sqlite), so it's not clear to me now how to keep intermediate values in variables

Is there some workaround (don't use stored procedure) to perform the same calculations efficiently using sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database, i.e., it is designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language.

It might be possible to import that log file into a database file, but the whole point of having a database is to *store* the data, which is neither a direct goal for this problem, nor would it increase efficiency (in fact, the extra file would make everything slower).

Doing the calculations is comparatively easy:

```
SELECT total, failed, failed/total AS ratio
FROM (SELECT SUM(col1 + col2) AS total,
             SUM(CASE col3 WHEN 404 THEN col1 + col2 END) AS failed
      FROM MyTable)
```

but this is not the slow part of this problem, the import would be.

This is an example where `awk` is the best tool for the job.

Comment: Yes, import is slow, moreover it requires data validation (log can be incomplete sometimes because of app failures).   
But in some specific situations it really worths.  
On my test data set I got 1m47s (sqlite) vs. 15m27s(awk) using your query  
I understand it supposed to be used for embedding, but I think I can use it as replacement for awk oneliners (at least I hope so)

Comment: Your timing doesn't include the import, does it? SQLite is useful if you want to do multiple queries.

Comment: Sure, import timing not included, it took abt 30 mins, so I will use sqlite only if I will need to get data from the same logs more than 5 times